# Null space and rank of block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Sorry that the title is a bit ambiguous, I can't think of anything better.

Given a matrix

$
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B^T \\
B & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

where $C$ is **not singular** (so rank(C) = n+m), $0\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is the zero matrix, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m \leq n$. Assume that $A$ is not full rank.

If $rank(B) = m$ and $null(B) \cap null(A) = \{0\}$, then $A$ has rank at least $n - m$.

Why is the above statement true?

There's some intuition about "$null(B) \cap null(A) = \{0\}$" which I just don't see.

Edit: If it helps anymore, I've included the snippet of where this came from: [snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ZTc.png)

Comment: The nullity of $A$ or of $C$?

Comment: I've just edited the statement to make it more clear. The nullity of A. C is not singular, so it's nullity is $n+m$.

Comment: Is the $O$ matrix a zero matrix?

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment, I meant that C is not singular, so it's $rank(C) = n+m$, and $nullity(C) = 0$ . And yes, $O$ is the zero matrix. I've edited this now :)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to see with all the hypotheses, except what's in the statement:
the rank-nullity theorem says that
$$\DeclareMathOperator\rk{rank}\rk A+\dim\ker A=n,$$
hence if $\rk A \ge r$, then $\;\dim\ker A\le n-r$.

*Added:*

Note the hypothesis $C$ has full rank implies $B$ has full rank, so $\ker B=0$, and the hypothesis $\ker A\cap\ker B=0$ is redundant.

Without the hypothesis on $C$, $\ker A\cap\ker B=0$ implies $\ker C=0$

Comment: I get that part. But why does $rank(B) = m $ and $null(B) \cap null(A) = \{0 \}$ imply that $rank(A) \geq n-m$? The second half of the statement I understand.

Comment: That was not in your post. I'll have to think it over.

Comment: Sorry! - Yeah, I realised that I phrased it incorrectly. I've edited it again.

Comment: I've included the snippet of where this came from, in case it helps.
I agree that the hypothesis ker $A$ $\cap$ ker $B$ seems redundant now that you've pointed it out.